# database-migration with flyway

Tags: migration, database-migration, flyway

**Flyway Migrate** command error

### ***ERROR:***
Unable to create schema "testDB"

SQL State  : 99999
Error Code : 65096
Message    : ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Caused by: Error : 65096, Position : 12, Sql = CREATE USER "testDB" IDENTIFIED BY "FFllyywwaayy00!!", OriginalSql = CREATE USER "testDB" IDENTIFIED BY "FFllyywwaayy00!!", Error Msg = ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name